# Subversion: File properties

Tags: linux, svn

I am using Subversion to manage my python code. But I have no idea how to put the file properties of my configuration file.

For example I have the configuration file checked in on my development platform. I want to make sure that

1. After the configuration file is being checked out. The SVN up process should ignore the modified configuration file.
2. On the server side I have the golden configuration file. Therefore the SVN commit should ignore the configuration file as well.

I have no idea how to set the properties of the configuration file so I am seeking help here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This comes up enough that it's [in the Subversion FAQ](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit)

Short version: Create (and version) a "template" configuration file. Users check out a WC, make a filesystem local (not `svn`) copy which is to be ignored by Subversion, and then modify that copy.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at my [pre-commit](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) hook.

But first, uou need to remove that configuration file from your Subversion repository. Instead, add a configuration template that developers can copy and use.

Once you remove the configuration file from your repository, you want to set `svn:ignore` to ignore it. This way, it doesn't accidentally get added if a user does a `svn add *` or sees it when they do a `svn status`.

However, if you want to be absolutely certain that this configuration file is never added to the project, you need a pre-commit hook that will refuse a commit if a user does add it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you tell SVN to ignore the file?

```
$ cd path/to/config/file
$ svn delete --keep-local config.file
$ svn propset svn:ignore config.file
$ svn commit
```

What this does is first tell SVN that it should stop tracking the file (`svn delete`), then we set the `svn:ignore`poperty on the directory in which the file resides, and then we commit these changes.

If you still want the configuration file to be tracked by SVN, then you can either commit your changes excluding the modifications on the file, or [external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) the file in and be sure to ignore externals when committing.